# How to calculate & draw metrics of scripted metrics in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, vega-lite

### Problem description

we have log files from different devices parsed into our elastic search database, line by line. The log files are built as a ring buffer, so they always have a fixed size of 1000 lines. They can be manually exported whenever needed. After import and parsing in elastic search each document represents a single line of a log file with the following information:

```
DeviceID:       12345
FileType:       ErrorLog
FileTimestamp:  2022-05-10 01:23:45
LogTimestamp:   2022-05-05 01:23:45
LogMessage:     something very important here
```

Now I want to have a statistic on the timespan that usually is covered by that fixed amount of lines. Because, depending on the intensity of the usage of the device, a varying amount of log entries is generated and the files can cover from just a few days to several months... But since the log files are split into individual lines it is not that trivial (I suppose).

**My goal is to have a chart that shows me a "histogram" of the different log file timespans...**

### First Try: Visualize library > Data table

I started by creating a `Data table` in the `Visualize library` where I was able to aggregate the data as follows:

**I added 3 Buckets** --> so I have all lines bucketed by their original file:

1. Split rows DeviceID.keyword
2. Split rows FileType.keyword
3. Split rows FileTimestamp

... **and 2 Metrics** --> to show the log file timespan (I couldn't find a way to create a `max-min` metric, so I started with individual metrics for max and min):

1. Metric Min LogTimeStamp
2. Metric Max LogTimeStamp

This results in the following query:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "DeviceID.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "FileType.keyword",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            },
            "size": 5
          },
          "aggs": {
            "4": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "FileTimestamp",
                "order": {
                  "_key": "desc"
                },
                "size": 100
              },
              "aggs": {
                "1": {
                  "min": {
                    "field": "LogTimeStamp"
                  }
                },
                "5": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "LogTimeStamp"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  ...
}
```

... and this output:

```
DeviceID     FileType     FileTimestamp           Min LogTimestamp        Max LogTimestamp 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345        ErrorLog     2022-05-10 01:23:45     2022-04-10 01:23:45     2022-05-10 01:23:45
...
```

**Looks good so far!** The expected result would be exactly 1 month for this example.

**But my research showed, that it is not possible to add the desired metrics here, so I needed to try something else...**

### Second Try: Vizualize library > Custom visualization (Vega-Lite)

So I started some more research and found out, that `vega` might be a possibility. I already was able to transfer the bucket part from the first attempt there and I also added a `scripted metric` to automatically `calculate the timespan` (instead of min & max), so far, so good. The request body looks as follows:

```
body: {
    "aggs": {
        "DeviceID": {
            "terms": { "field": "DeviceID.keyword" }, 
            "aggs": {
                "FileType": {
                    "terms": { "field": "FileType.keyword" } ,
                    "aggs": {
                        "FileTimestamp": {
                            "terms": { "field": "FileTimestamp" } ,
                            "aggs": {
                                "timespan": {
                                    "scripted_metric": {
                                        "init_script": "state.values = [];",
                                        "map_script": "state.values.add(doc['@timestamp'].value);",
                                        "combine_script": "long min = Long.MAX_VALUE; long max = 0; for (t in state.values) { long tms = t.toInstant().toEpochMilli(); if(tms > max) max = tms; if(tms < min) min = tms; } return [max,min];",
                                        "reduce_script": "long min = Long.MAX_VALUE; long max = 0; for (a in states) { if(a[0] > max) max = a[0]; if(a[1] < min) min = a[1]; } return max-min;"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },      
    "size": 0,
}
```

...with this response (unnecessary information removed to reduce complexity):

```
{
    "took": 12245,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": { ... },
    "hits": {  ...  },
    "aggregations": {
        "DeviceID": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "12345",
                    "FileType": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": "ErrorLog",
                                "FileTimeStamp": {
                                    "buckets": [
                                        {
                                            "key": 1638447972000,
                                            "key_as_string": "2021-12-02T12:26:12.000Z",
                                            "doc_count": 1000,
                                            "timespan": {
                                                "value": 31339243240
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": 1636023881000,
                                            "key_as_string": "2021-11-04T11:04:41.000Z",
                                            "doc_count": 1000,
                                            "timespan": {
                                                "value": 31339243240
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "InfoLog",
                                "FileTimeStamp": {
                                    "buckets": [
                                        {
                                            "key": 1635773438000,
                                            "key_as_string": "2021-11-01T13:30:38.000Z",
                                            "doc_count": 1000,
                                            "timespan": {
                                                "value": 2793365000
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": 1636023881000,
                                            "key_as_string": "2021-11-04T11:04:41.000Z",
                                            "doc_count": 1000,
                                            "timespan": {
                                                "value": 2643772000
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                      }
                },
                {
                    "key": "12346",
                    "FileType": {
                        ...
                    }
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Yeah, it seems to work! Now I have the timespan for each original log file.**

### Question

Now I am stuck with:

1. I want to **average the timespans for each original log file** (identified via the combination of DeviceID + FileType + FileTimeStamp) to prevent devices with multiple log files imported to have a higher weight, than devices with only 1 log file imported. I tried to `add another aggregation` for the avg, but I couldn't figure out where to put so that the result of the `scripted_metric` is used. My closest attempt was to put a `avg_bucket` after the FileTimeStamp bucket:

Request:

```
body: {
    "aggs": {
        "DeviceID": {
            "terms": { "field": "DeviceID.keyword" }, 
            "aggs": {
                "FileType": {
                    "terms": { "field": "FileType.keyword" } ,
                    "aggs": {
                        "FileTimestamp": {
                            "terms": { "field": "FileTimestamp" } ,
                            "aggs": {
                                "timespan": {
                                    "scripted_metric": {
                                        "init_script": "state.values = [];",
                                        "map_script": "state.values.add(doc['FileTimestamp'].value);",
                                        "combine_script": "long min = Long.MAX_VALUE; long max = 0; for (t in state.values) { long tms = t.toInstant().toEpochMilli(); if(tms > max) max = tms; if(tms < min) min = tms; } return [max,min];",
                                        "reduce_script": "long min = Long.MAX_VALUE; long max = 0; for (a in states) { if(a[0] > max) max = a[0]; if(a[1] < min) min = a[1]; } return max-min;"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
// new part - start
                        "avg_timespan": {
                            "avg_bucket": {
                                "buckets_path": "FileTimestamp>timespan"
                            }
                        }
// new part - end
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },      
    "size": 0,
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> EsError: buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [InternalScriptedMetric] at aggregation [timespan]

**So is it the right spot? (but not applicable to a scripted metric) Or am I on the wrong path?**

2. I need to **plot all this**, but I can't find my way through all the buckets, etc.
   I read about flattening (which would probably be a good idea, so (if done by the server) the result would not be that complex), but don't know where and how to put the flattening transformation.

I imagine the resulting chart like this:

- **x-axis = log file timespan**, where the timespan is "binned" according to a given step size (e.g. 1 day), so there are only bars for each bin (1 = 0-1days, 2 = 1-2days, 3 = 2-3days, etc.) and not for all the different timespans of log files
- **y-axis = count of devices**
- **type: lines or vertical bars, split by file type**

e.g. something like this:

[image: log-file-timespan-histogram]

**Any help is really appreciated! Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the privileges to create a [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html), then the elastic painless example [Getting duration by using bucket script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-painless-examples.html#painless-bucket-script) can do exactly what you want. It creates a new index where all documents are grouped according to your needs.

**To create the transform**:

1. go to *Stack Management > Transforms > + Create a transform*
2. select **Edit JSON config** for the *Pivot configuration object*
3. paste & apply the JSON below
4. check whether the result is the expected in the *Transform preview*
5. fill out the rest of the transform details + save the transform

**JSON config**

```
{
  "group_by": {
    "DeviceID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "DeviceID.keyword"
      }
    },
    "FileType": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "FileType.keyword"
      }
    },
    "FileTimestamp": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "FileTimestamp"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "TimeStampStats": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "@timestamp"
      }
    },
    "TimeSpan": {
      "bucket_script": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "first": "TimeStampStats.min",
          "last": "TimeStampStats.max"
        },
        "script": "params.last - params.first"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create a chart from the new index, for example with these settings:

- Vertical Bars
- Metrics:

  - Y-axis = "Count"
- Buckets:

  - X-axis = "TimeSpan"
  - Split series = "FileType"